# Repeater with textboxes programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

My object is to create something like table with number of columns and 5 rows.

I decided that i can do that with asp.net control repeater. Maybe there is a better way you should tell me?

So what i need as result is a number of columns in the first one there will be headers, in the next three rows it should be textboxes, with appropriete name like the txt+name of the header, and the last row should have checkboxes also with appropriete name.

So what i wanted to do is define one column as it should look like and then do the rest programmatically, or just bind IList (the names of the headers) and the other columns should be created.

Is this possible and how to do that?

What i have now is something like that:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
    <table border="1" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td>%#Container.DataItem("value")%</td>
        </tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>   
    <tr>
        <td><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"/></td>
        <td><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"/></td>
        <td><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"/></td>
    </tr>

    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>

    </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: I think this can be done with Nested Repeaters and using the OnItemDataBound Event to file each Section/Repeater. Good luck